# Django Query Set to get Row value as column name

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

These are my models:

```
class Build(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=56)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=512, null=True, blank=True)


class Case(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1024, null=True, blank=True)


class Result(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    result_build = models.ForeignKey(Build, related_name='result_build', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    result_case = models.ForeignKey(Case, related_name='result_case', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I need a django `QuerySet` to get data like below:

```
....................................................
: case_name : case_description : build_X : build_Y :
:...........:..................:.........:.........:
:  test1    :   case1          :  PASS   :  FAIL   :
:  test2    :   case2          :  FAIL   :  PASS   :
:...........:..................:.........:.........:
```

where `case_name` and `case_description` are fields from `Case` model.

build_X and build_Y are the two build names available in `Build` model
and PASS and FAIL are the status for different cases and builds from `Result` model.

Comment: You have an implicit many-to-many relation between `Build` and `Case` through `Result`. Is there any reason you don't want or you can't declare this relation explicitly?

Comment: Could you please detail about declaring relation explicitly with above example, that would be help me understand better

Comment: Basically here  i want value as column name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classical case for many-to-many relationship with a through model. The model classes can be refactored as following:

```
class Build(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=56)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=512, null=True, blank=True)


class Case(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1024, null=True, blank=True)
    builds = models.ManyToManyField('Build', through='Result', related_name='cases')


class Result(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    build = models.ForeignKey('Build', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    case = models.ForeignKey('Case', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

We can also call the properties of `Result` simply `build` and `case`, without redundancy in the names. Although `related_name` doesn't bother, we don't really need it here.

Now you can use the m2m relationship to query your models:

```
case = Case.objects.get(pk=1) # get Case object with primary key 1
case.builds.all() # get all Build objects related to case
build = Build.objects.get(pk=1) # get Build object with primary key 1
build.cases.all() # get all Case objects related to build
# UPDATE
# get Result objects for the "case" with pk=1 retrieved before
results = Result.objects.filter(case=case)
# output each entry as row with all property values
for r in results:
    print(r.case.name, r.case.description, r.build.name, r.build, description, r.status)
```

You can also use `.filter` to narrow down your query result.

EDIT:

Here is one possible way to create a matrix table. This is a code you can put in your view:

```
cases = Case.objects.all()
builds = Build.objects.all()
matrix = []
for c in cases:
    result = {}
    result['case'] = c
    result['status'] = []
    for b in builds:
        result['status'].append(Result.objects.filter(
                                    case=c,
                                    build=b
                               ).values_list('status', flat=True))
    matrix.append(result)
```

Now you should have a table with a dictionary for every case. Pass `builds` and `matrix` as context to your template. Then you can iterate over the `builds` to create the table header (take care to leave space for a column or two in the beginning for listing the cases). Then iterate over the `matrix` and create the table body. First get the `case` for the first column (or the first two columns) and then output the `status`.

I hope this can point you the way. Once you have the right result you can further optimize the performance.

EDIT 2:

Here is an example how the table could look like.
Pass `builds` and `matrix` from the code snippet above as context to the template:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Case name</th>
    <th>Case description</th>
    {% for b in builds %}
      <th>{{ b.name }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  {% for row in matrix %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ row.case.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ row.case.description }}</td>
      {% for s in row.status %}
        <td>{{ s.0 }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

In the first `for` loop we create a table header with two column headers for case name and case description and one column header for each build.
In the second `for` loop we create a table row for each case. In the nested loop we output the status.

It is a very simple approach and probably can be further optimized, but I leave that to you.

Comment: Actually i need the values from `Result` model not from `Case` model, because the status are available in `Result`, Again requirement is i need `build_name`  as column name while querying Result table

Comment: @santosh You'll get the values from the `Result` model too. Please check the update. Regarding your requirement with the column name I think you're mixing the concept of Django QuerySet and SQL query. Where do you want to display that table? HTML page? Or something else?

Comment: I want to display in an HTML table

Comment: Couple of things,my requirement still looking complex, I need to get all cases something like `case = Case.objects.all()` and also need to get as well like `build = Build.objects.all()` and Most important thing is. a `case` can have more than one status in such a case, while querying `Result` model `r.status` needs to be a list with multiple status per build. Basically i want to generate table in html as described in html. I know i am asking too many things, since i am new to this both django and SQL please help me with this

Comment: @santosh What you actually want is a matrix table. I'll update my answer little bit later.

Comment: @santosh I thought you could solve your problem, however I added a table example. Hopefully you are on the right path now.